# Cakephp 3: execute custom command from command

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.6

In CakPHP 3.6.0 [Console Commands](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/commands.html) have been added to replace Shells and Tasks long term.

I'm currently designing a cronjob command to execute other commands in different time intervals. So I want to run a command from a Command class like this:

```php
namespace App\Command;
// ...

class CronjobCommand extends Command
{
    public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
    {
        // Run other command
    }
}
```

For Shells / Tasks it is possible to use `Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher`:

```php
$shell = new ShellDispatcher();
$output = $shell->run(['cake', $task]);
```

but this does not work for Commands. As I did not find any information in the docs, any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply instantiate the command and then run it, like this:

```
try {
    $otherCommand = new \App\Command\OtherCommand();
    $result = $otherCommand->run(['--foo', 'bar'], $io);
} catch (\Cake\Console\Exception\StopException $e) {
    $result = $e->getCode();
}
```

CakePHP 3.8 will introduce a convenience method that helps with this. Quote from the upcoming docs:

> You may need to call other commands from your command. You can use
>   `executeCommand` to do that::
>
> ```
> // You can pass an array of CLI options and arguments.
> $this->executeCommand(OtherCommand::class, ['--verbose', 'deploy']);
>
> // Can pass an instance of the command if it has constructor args
> $command = new OtherCommand($otherArgs);
> $this->executeCommand($command, ['--verbose', 'deploy']);
> ```

See also **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/13163**.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Works perfect! Great to see, that CakePHP 3.8 will provide an additional function for this.